# Values of each bar is not showing at the right spot (Matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The value of each bar is not showing at each bar. And, also only one type of bars is showing. Where should I do some adjustments?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [25, 30, 20]
b = [30, 20, 27]
c = [30, 25, 37]
d = [25, 40, 20]

x_ticks = ['Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3']
y = [a, b, c, d]
index = np.arange(3)
plt.xticks(index + .3, x_ticks)

plt.bar(index + 0.00, a, color ='r', width = 0.22)
plt.bar(index + 0.20, b, color ='g', width = 0.22)
plt.bar(index + 0.40, c, color ='b', width = 0.22)
plt.bar(index + 0.60, d, color ='k', width = 0.22)

for a, b in enumerate(y):
    plt.text(a, b, str(b))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You have 4 values but 3 types. Please describe clearly how you want your plot to look like.

Comment: I think, mine is not clear indeed. I want to display four different sets of bars in each type. But mine is showing only one same sets of bar in each type. For example, a will have different value in each type, so will b.

Comment: So why do you use a single value for each set, i.e. `a` is 75. To have different bar height, you need to set it to have several values, e.g. `a = [75,76,77]`.

Comment: I will fix it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two loops to annotate the bars, one to loop over the types and one to loop over the subgroups.

```
for i,s in enumerate(y):
    for j, t in enumerate(s):
        plt.text(j+i*.2, t, str(t), ha="center")
```